# What is the advantage of using useDebounce insted of using just debounce function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

I have noticed people using this kind of useDebounced hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function useDebounce(value: any, delay: number) {

    const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

    useEffect(
        () => {
            const handler = setTimeout(() => {
                setDebouncedValue(value);
            }, delay);

            return () => {
                clearTimeout(handler);
            };
        }
    );

    return debouncedValue;
}
```

*Taken from https://dev.to/gabe_ragland/debouncing-with-react-hooks-jci

What is the advantage of using the hook, and not just simple javascript debounce, like in lodash library??

Comment: (Side note: That `useDebounce` hook is missing the dependencies array, see [this one instead](https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/). It'll work anyway, I think, it'll just run the code in the `useEffect` callback much more often than necessary.)

Comment: Other than reactivity and doing that in the "react way" I don't think there is any other relevant reason.

Comment: "*not just simple javascript debounce, like in lodash library?*" - well I don't see how the lodash debouce is much simpler than the hook. And it looks like you need a library for both? Also, the `useDebounce` hook is doing something different - can you please suggest how you are using it, and how you would use lodash's `debounce` instead?

Comment: What does this have to do with functional programming?